# Can not change a value of a struct in a dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I declared a dictionary as follow

```
fileprivate var subscribedCentrals : Dictionary<UUID, Dictionary<CBUUID, ContactDataSendProgress>> = Dictionary<UUID, Dictionary<CBUUID, ContactDataSendProgress>>()
```

Now in a method of my class I go through that dictionary with the following code:

```
for (_, ListOfCharacteristics) in subscribedCentrals {
            for (_, var SendProgress) in ListOfCharacteristics {
                self.sendMessage(to: SendProgress.central!, forCharacteristic: SendProgress.sendingType!, withData: SendProgress.data!, onIndex: &SendProgress.dataIndex, withEOM: &SendProgress.sendingEOM)
                SendProgress.dataIndex = 24
            }
        }
```

Since the two parameters onIndex and withEOM are `inout` I would expect the values in the struct contained in the dictionary would be updated. But the next time I go through the dictionary I still have the old values.

What do I need to change, so that the new values will be saved in the dictionary?

Comment: You need to update (assign back) all `ListOfCharacteristics` also in (to) the outer dictionary.

Comment: Thanks that did it